# Why am I getting an unexpected Error in Snowflake PUT load?

Tags: csv, put, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a local csv file to my staging area in Snowflake, and am using:

```
PUT file:'//Users/mark 1/Downloads/pp-complete.csv' @~ auto_compress=true;
```

But I keep getting the error:

> SQL compilation error: parse error line 1 at position 9 near '39'.
>   syntax error line 1 at position 74 unexpected '

As far as I can tell, there's nothing 'wrong' with the SCV file. It opens fine in SublimeEdit and Excel, and I can't see anything 'funny' in there to account for this.

Am stuck now.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
PUT file://C:\\Users\\mark 1\\Downloads\\pp-complete.csv @~ auto_compress=true;
```

Above command worked, added snip for your reference. Instead of single quotes use double slash to escape your path. So change your put command as like below and try.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
PUT 'file:///Users/mark 1/Downloads/pp-complete.csv' @~ auto_compress=true;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need single quotes, and an extra slash:

```
PUT 'file:///Users/mark 1/Downloads/pp-complete.csv' @~ auto_compress=true;
```

Refer to the examples [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/put.html#examples)

**EDIT**: I realize you probably do need the quotes because of the space in your file name. but I think the issue is the missing slash